# Parsing idx file or string to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I would like to parse the following idx file: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2022/QTR1/company.20220112.idx into Pandas DataFrame.

I use the following code to check how it would look like as a text file:

```
import os, requests

base_path = '/Users/GunardiLin/Desktop/Insider_Ranking/temp/'
current_dirs = os.listdir(path=base_path)
local_filename =  f'20200102'
local_file_path = '/'.join([base_path, local_filename])

if local_filename in base_path:
    print(f'Skipping index file for {local_filename} because it is already saved.')

url = f'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2020/QTR1/company.20200102.idx'

r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers= {'user-agent': 'MyName myname@outlook.com'})
with open(local_file_path, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=10240):
        f.write(chunk)
```

[image]

Next I would like to build a parser that is fault tollerance, because it should parse **daily** a new idx file into pd.DataFrame.

My idea was to use string manipulation, but it would be very complicated and not fault tollerance.

I would be thankful if someone can show the best practice to parse and give a boilerplate code.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you would like to see as output?  A dataframe?  Another file?  Do you need the information above the line (other than the header info)?

Comment: And is this a file structure that is always the same - Leading information followed by header lines, followed by the dashed line, followed by the data columns?

Comment: @jch : the output should be a pandas DataFrame with the content starting from line 9 in my screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is mostly a fixed width file you could use pandas `read_fwf` to read this file.  You can skip over the leading information (via `skiprows=`) and get straight to the data.  The column names are predefined and assigned when read:

```
idx_path = 'company.20220112.idx'
names = ['Company Name','Form Type','CIK','Date Filed','File Name']
df = pd.read_fwf(idx_path, colspecs=[(0,61),(62,74),(74,84),(86,94),(98,146)], names=names, skiprows=11)
df.head(10)

                                         Company Name Form Type      CIK Date Filed                                    File Name  
0   005 - Series of IPOSharks Venture Master Fund,...         D  1888451   20220112  edgar/data/1888451/0001888451-22-000002.txt  
1           10X Capital Venture Acquisition Corp. III    EFFECT  1848948   20220111  edgar/data/1848948/9999999995-22-000102.txt  
2                              110 White Partners LLC         D  1903845   20220112  edgar/data/1903845/0001884293-22-000001.txt  
3                                       15 Beach, MHC         3  1903509   20220112  edgar/data/1903509/0001567619-22-001073.txt  
4                                       15 Beach, MHC    SC 13D  1903509   20220112  edgar/data/1903509/0000943374-22-000014.txt  
5                                      170 Valley LLC         D  1903913   20220112  edgar/data/1903913/0001903913-22-000001.txt  
6                         1st FRANKLIN FINANCIAL CORP     424B3    38723   20220112    edgar/data/38723/0000038723-22-000003.txt  
7                         1st FRANKLIN FINANCIAL CORP     424B3    38723   20220112    edgar/data/38723/0000038723-22-000004.txt  
8                               215 BF Associates LLC         D  1904145   20220112  edgar/data/1904145/0001904145-22-000001.txt  
9                       2401 Midpoint Drive REIT, LLC         D  1903337   20220112  edgar/data/1903337/0001903337-22-000001.txt
```